# onClick error - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very new to this. My buttons weren't responding to clicks. I added  android:onClick="onClick" to the xml file. Now i get the error below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class testapp.two.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'buttonMinus'
```

Please help, java code along with the manifest file and main xml are included below.

Thanks.

```
package testapp.two;

import testapp.two.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button okButton, minusButton, plusButton;
    TextView textScore, scoreCard;
    int score = 95;
    private static final String TAG = "GolfScore";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate started"); 

    okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
    minusButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
    plusButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
    textScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textScore);
    scoreCard = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreCard);


    //set button listeners
    okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));


    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate finished");
    }//onCreate

@Override   
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate");

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonMinus:
            score--;
            textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonPlus:
            score++;
            textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            break;

        case R.id.buttonOK:


            break;
        }//end of switch

    }//end of my onclick


}//end of MainActivity
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="@+id/buttonMinus, @+id/buttonPlus, @+id/textScore"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:text="Golf Score App"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="92"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreCard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Score card info goes here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think that when you use `android:onClick="onClick"` in xml, that you don't have to implement `onClickListener` in your `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1):

As 0xDEADC0DE says, you don't need the OnClickListener if you use the onClick attribute in your XML and vice versa.

The reason why the `onClick(View v)` method can't be found is the `Override`annotation. It depends to the `OnClickListener` this way. There is a "free" method without annotation needed that the method can be found if the onClick tag is used.

Now you have two options: get rid of the OnClicklistener and the association to the buttons or the onClick in your XML.

Edit:

Remove the `onClick` attributes from the RelativeLayout and the Buttons in your XML. In addition, remove `clickable` from your Buttons. If you set `clickable = true`, the View will get an empty OnClickListener automatically. This means your `OnClickListener` in your Activity will not be called.

Comment: I previously did not have the onClick in my XML. But then nothing happened when I clicked the buttons.

Comment: Thanks Steve, did you what said. The error is gone but nothing happens when I click the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `android:onClick="onClick"` from your XML.

Note that it is preferrable to make a single `OnClickListener` for each button rather than one big `OnClickListener` that has to check the `id` to decide what to do.

Comment: Eh, second part is entirely opinion. I prefer a single onClick method with the switch.

Comment: @Coeffect I removed the 'onClick' statement from the XML but my buttons still don't respond to clicks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @fredo124 Please post a new question with your revised code. Also describe the exact steps you follow when you run the app and what happens. Then tell us what you **want** to happen instead.